# mt Bootstrap 3 grid is not working on codeigniter 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I need your help. I cant get the grid layout to work. The helper url has been auto loaded and im sure that the bootstrap.min.css, jquery.js and the bootstrap.min.js were on the right folder and they are loaded. I could use alert alert-success and some components but i cant make the grid layout to work. This is how my view looks like.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Units</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('script/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>"/>

</head>
<body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('script/js/jquery.js')?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('script/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of output do you get from `site_url` function?

Comment: just open chrome / developer tools and switch to the network tab - make a refresh of your site and look if there is anything red lined ... even if you say the files are loaded i don't believe it ;)

Comment: this is the output of site_url()   http://127.0.0.1/invent/script/js/jquery.js

Comment: Sorry f12 on chrome then console right? nothings on a red line, if it has then at least i have a clue about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

U can try base_url instead of site_url

- site_url: Returns base_url + index_page + uri_string
- base_url:    Returns base_url + uri_string

Comment: i tried to change site_url to base_url but same result happends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your .row div inside a .container div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah maybe they are needed because of the paddings - but the float should always work ....

Comment: I tried to to put the class="container" in the body  tag but still not working